# Can git be installed locally (including its dependencies)

Tags: git, sles

I've developed a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script which needs a specific version of [git](/questions/tagged/git) (2.11.1).

Each developer in my team has his/her own virtual machine on the same remote physic server.
My colleagues need that script, the problem is that some of them are using the shared [git](/questions/tagged/git) which is outdated and there is no way to update it, and the others are using their own installation `/usr/bin/git`, which is not always up-to-date either.

In order for that script to work, the best solution I decided to work on is that before the script runs, it will install the wanted git LOCALLY (I mean under `~/custom/empty_dir`), but this didn't work as I'm getting many errors when running `make all doc info` as described in [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#_installing_from_source)

```
$make all doc info
    * new build flags
    CC credential-store.o
In file included from credential-store.c:1:0:
cache.h:40:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zlib.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

Isn't it possible to install [git](/questions/tagged/git) locally as explained above without of course impacting `/usr/bin/git` and `/company/shared/softwares/git/bin/git` ?

> ps: PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"

Comment: @dsstorefile no it is not, however `zlib.c` is

Comment: Those "git-scm" build instructions tell you to install several dependencies, including the `zlib-devel` or `libz-dev` package.  Did you do that?

Comment: @JigglyNaga the idea is to install git and its dependencies locally as I said...so no I didn't do that. I keep hoping that there is a way to do it :)

Comment: Virtually _any_ software can be installed under `$HOME` in Unix (if that's what you mean by "locally"), provided that the dependencies are met. Of course, the dependencies may be installed under `$HOME` as well.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes that's what I meant...so if I understood you right I need to install dependencies locally beside it so that works....it seems much of work to me....Thanks any way :)

Comment: @smarber It may be indeed a lot of work. So if you explained your assertion " needs a specific version of git (2.11.1)." maybe people could provide alternate solution. Why do you need this specific version?

Answer (score 0):

So, installing `libz-dev` should solve an issue:

```
apt-get install libz-dev
```